# A command for bochs that skips a "call", "jmp", or "int" instruction

Tags: bochs

I'm using bochs as a debugger. I use the "s" command to step through my code. My problem is however, that whenever an "int" instruction comes, it starts stepping through BIOS code. Is there a command I can enter to get it to skip all the BIOS code and go back to my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I subscribed to the bochs mailing list and sent in an email asking my question. In an email, I got an answer that I should use the "b" command to set a breakpoint after the "int" instruction, like this:

```
b <address>
```

And then I should use the "c" command to continue until the breakpoint.

Now, in order to figure out what the address of the instruction after the "int" instruction is, I disassembled my code using `ndisasm` and found the instruction after the "int" instruction:

```
0000000A  B40E              mov ah,0xe
```

I then took `0000000A`, added `0x7C00` to it (because the bootfile is loaded into memory starting at `0x7C00`) and that's where I set my breakpoint.